# Customize textbox in wp8

Tags: windows-phone-8, textbox

[image]

I want to customize the textbox and as shown in the figure above I want to make textbox look like a simple line in my app instead of a usual textbox. Help is required in accomplishing it. Any code snippet available kindly give me.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this:

```
<TextBox BorderThickness="0,0,0,1"/>
```

Comment: yes it's look has become similar to what i want .. but the issue is when i tap on it to write something it shows me the complete textbox look . so is there a way that when i write in it, it shows me only the line instead of the box.